# How can I define Operator == when comparing vectors of classes?

Tags: c++, iterator, operator-keyword

I want to use the fonction find in order to find a element in a vector of struct (with the atributs x and y),

But i'm getting the error with no matching operator==. I tried to redefine it, but i'm still getting the same error message:

> Error: no match for « operator== » (operand types are « const coordenates » and « const coordenates »)   { return *__it == _M_value; }

```
struct coordenates {
int x;
int y;

bool operator ==(const coordenates &a){
    if (x == a.x && y == a.y)
        {return true;}
    return false;
}

 bool findInVector(const std::vector<coordenates> &vecOfElements, const int &i, const int &j)
{
    bool presence;
    coordenates element;
    element.x = i;
    element.y = j;

if(std::find(vecOfElements.begin(), vecOfElements.end(), element) == vecOfElements.end()) {
    presence = false;}
else{presence = true;}
    return presence;
}
```

Comment: Define `operator==` as const member function. `bool operator ==(const coordenates &a) const {...}`

Answer (score 4):

It's passed as a `const coordinates` so your `operator==` must be marked `const` as well to match:

```
bool operator ==(const coordenates &a) const
```

Comment: @Bathsheba I must say I don't move too much so you're probably right good sir.

Comment: @Quentin This has been going on for a while sadly. I'm disappointed in myself too.